# Comparing an array index to a String?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to compare an index from my array of char's to a string, I'm using the .equals method but I'm running into errors. Any help?

```
if (j[1].equals("A"))
{j[1] = 10;}
```

I keep getting this error:

```
int cannot be dereferenced
else if (j[1].equals("A"))
```

Comment: `char` is a primitive data type, not an object.

Comment: Do you have an array of chars or Strings?

Comment: Relevent question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Use `.equals` for Strings with other Strings. `j[1]` is not a String.

Comment: I have an array of Char's that are mixed with numbers and the Letters A to F. What I would like is to be able to say, if the Char is = to A then assign the value 10 to a new variable or the same index in the array, whatever is easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to compare single characters, you need to use the `==` operator because `char` is a primitive type and Java does not allow to call methods on primitive types. Also, you can't directly compare with a string, you need to compare to a `char`. Constants of type `char` are written with single quotes as opposed to double quotes which denote String constants.

Thus your code would be:

```
if (j[1] == 'A')
```

You should then use another variable for storing the value `10`. Although you could theoretically store it in the array (characters are just numbers, too), this would be very confusing code. Thus use an additional `int` variable.

Also note that in Java, you should speak of `char`s, not of `Char`s. The reason is that there is also a class name `Character` which also represents a single character, but as an object instead of a primitive type. Thus when you say `Char`, it is not clear if you mean `char` of `Character`.

Comment: This explanation helped a lot! Thank you, I will be keeping that in mind!

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
if (j[1] == 'A')
```

If the `j` array contains `char`s, then you must compare its values with another `char`, not a `String` (even if the string has length 1) - they're different data types. And because a `char` is a primitive type, `==` is used for equality comparisons.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. I'll keep the data types in mind next time and hopefully thats one mistake I won't be making again!

Comment: @user1861156 you're welcome! please don't forget to accept the answer that was most helpful for you, by clicking on the check mark to its left

Answer (score 0):

If j[1] is an array of `char` (the primitive, not the object `Character`) then you cannot not call the equals method on it, just like you cannot call `1.equals("A")`.

So, this would work instead (using objects)

```
    char[] array = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
    boolean equals = array[0].equals('a'); // Cannot invoke equals(char) on
                                            // the primitive type char
    Character.valueOf('a').equals(Character.valueOf(array[0])); //This works
```

Or this, using primitives:

```
    char[] array = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
    boolean anotherEquals = array[0] == 'a'; // This works
```